# How to add more than one column when join?

Tags: sql, postgresql, join

I have two tables:

Groups: group_id, group_name

Students: student_id, group_id, first_name, last_name

I wanna make query that shows group id, group name and number of students, but i can't add group name.
Now i have smth like this:

```
public String findGroupsByStudentsNumber(int expectedStudentsNumber) {
        return " SELECT students.group_id, COUNT(student_id) AS Number_of_students " +
                "FROM students " +
                "LEFT JOIN groups ON students.group_id = groups.group_id " +
                "GROUP BY students.group_id " +
                "HAVING COUNT(student_id) <= " + expectedStudentsNumber +
                " ORDER BY students.group_id";
    }
```

And output:

```
| group_id   | number_of_students  | 
---------------------------------------
| 0          | 24                  | 
| 1          | 14                  | 
| 2          | 13                  | 
| 3          | 28                  | 
| 4          | 30                  | 
| 5          | 26                  | 
| 6          | 23                  | 
| 7          | 30                  | 
| 8          | 12                  |
```

How can i add group name in this query?

Comment: Add it both to the `select` *and* the `group by` clauses.

Comment: Also, the question itself has nothing to do with java, except for the fact that you're using the query in a Java program (which is irrelevant to the question itself). Next time please create a [Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable Example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve) which, in this case, means just the query, without the java code surrounding it (and the java tag).

Comment: Alternatively use max (group_name) as group_name in select clause

Comment: It's always good practice to include sample date and expected result.

Comment: Learn to use parameters!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

just add it to the selected columns, as well as the group by

```
SELECT students.group_id, groups.group_name, COUNT(student_id) AS Number_of_students 
FROM students
LEFT JOIN groups ON students.group_id = groups.group_id 
GROUP BY students.group_id, groups.group_name
HAVING COUNT(student_id) <= " + expectedStudentsNumber
ORDER BY students.group_id
```

Answer (score 0):

Let me make two assumptions about your data model:

- `groups.group_id` is a primary key.
- `students.group_id` has a foreign key relationship, so it only contains valid values.  Although the relationship should be declared, it does not need to be.

If this is the case, the query that you want is presumably:

```
select g.group_id, g.group_name, count(s.student_id) as number_of_students
from groups g left join
     students s
     on g.group_id = s.group_id
group by g.group_id
having count(s.student_id) <= ?
order by g.group_id;
```

Notes:

- *All* groups have the option of being in the result set, even those with no students.  That appears to be the intent of your query.
- This uses a *parameter* for the maximum value rather than munging the query string.  The latter is dangerous and you should avoid it, especially if you are learning programming.
- When you aggregate by a primary key, Postgres lets you bring in whatever other columns you want from that table without using aggregation functions.
- Aggregating by primary keys also gives the optimizer more options.
- Table aliases make the query easier to write and to read.

Comment: Slight typo? Should  "on g.group_id = s.student_id" actual be "on g.group_id = s.group_id"?